# jQuery hide all images except first one in a generic way

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I want to show only the first image and hide others, this is how HTML looks like:

```
<div class="slider-image">
  <img src="html.png" alt="Html" />
  <img src="css.png" alt="Css" />
  <img src="jquery.png" alt="jQuery" />
</div>
```

In this example I want to see html.png but I have to consider more images so I have to find a generic solution.
I tried with:

```
$("div.slider-image").hide();
$("div.slider-image").eq(0).show();
```

but it shows every image, can someone help me?

Answer (score 2):

use [.not](https://api.jquery.com/not/)

Working snippet:

```js
$('.slider-image img').not(':eq(0)').hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slider-image">
    <img src="html.png" alt="Html" />
    <img src="css.png" alt="Css" />
    <img src="jquery.png" alt="jQuery" />
</div>
```

Or use `:not(:first-child)`

Working snippet:-

```js
$('.slider-image img:not(:first-child)').hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slider-image">
    <img src="html.png" alt="Html" />
    <img src="css.png" alt="Css" />
    <img src="jquery.png" alt="jQuery" />
</div>
```

Comment: The firts one works but it change the position of the image from left side to center

Comment: @SaraBriccoli  you have to adjust css accordingly

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need to use jQuery for this? You can achieve this with plain css:

```
.slider-image > img:not(:first-child) {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("div.slider-image img:not(:first-child)").hide();
```

Comment: Answer updated. Forgot the img selector. Plz Check.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="slider-image">
            <img src="html.png" alt="Html" />
            <img src="css.png" alt="Css" class="hide_img"/>
            <img src="jquery.png" alt="jQuery" class="hide_img" />
        </div>
```

**In script**

```
$("div.slider-image .hide_img").hide();
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't say that I can't change Html file

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple one line jQuery code...

`$("div.slider-image img").eq(0).siblings('img').hide();`

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.slider-image img:not(:first-child)').css('opacity':0);
```

it's not the right way but it's work @Anant Singh it's give to right answer but it's work for you

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below code. It's working perfectly. And image display in the center.

```js
$('.slider-image img:not(:first-child)').hide();
```

```css
.slider-image {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 10%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<div class="slider-image">
    <img src="html.png" alt="Html" />
    <img src="css.png" alt="Css" />
    <img src="jquery.png" alt="jQuery" />
</div>
```